# R: column reference to itself

Tags: r

Please, help!
I have w:

```
x   y
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   1
0   0
0   0
0   -1
0   0
0   0
0   1
0   0
0   -1
0   0
0   0
```

I would like to get:

```
x   y
0   0
0   0
0   0
1   1
1   0
1   0
0   -1
0   0
0   0
1   1
1   0
0   -1
0   0
0   0
```

I use R:

```
for (i in 2:length(w$x)) { w$x[i] = w$x[i-1] + w$y[i]}
```

Is it possible to do without the use of a loop statement?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assumes that you want to start with the initial value of 0 in the `x` column:

```
transform(w, x = cumsum(y))
##    x  y
## 1  0  0
## 2  0  0
## 3  0  0
## 4  1  1
## 5  1  0
## 6  1  0
## 7  0 -1
## 8  0  0
## 9  0  0
## 10 1  1
## 11 1  0
## 12 0 -1
## 13 0  0
## 14 0  0
```

Otherwise you can include the initial value:

```
transform(w, x = x[1] + cumsum(y))
```

The result here is the same.
Both of these assume that either `y[1]` is zero, or that you want to use the actual value if it is nonzero (your code ignores `y[1]`).

Comment: or `cbind(cumsum(y), y)`